# Spinners in List View

Tags: java, android, list, spinner, reset

I'm working on an app to identify trees. Therefore, I let the user answer questions about given characteristics, by choosing the appropriate characteristic out of a spinner. Because a tree has many characteristics, I have a whole list of spinners. So far, so good. Unfortunately, the spinners resets, as soon as the user scrolls them off the screen. It is essential, that I can avoid this!

So: How can I avoid this?

I greatly appreciate your help!

```
public class SearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SearchItem>{

    SearchAdapter() {
        super(SearchWizard.this, R.layout.question);
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View ret = convertView;

        if ( ret == null ) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ret = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question, null);
        }

        SearchItem item = getItem(position);
        String question = item.getQuestion();

        TextView question_text = (TextView) ret.findViewById(R.id.question_search);
        assert( question_text != null );
        question_text.setText(question);
        Spinner question_spinner = (Spinner ) ret.findViewById(R.id.question_spinner);
        assert( question_spinner != null );
        question_spinner.setPrompt(question);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchWizard.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, item.getOptions());
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        question_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        question_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener( new MyOnItemSelectedListener(position) );
        question_spinner.setSelection(2);

        return ret;
    }

}

enter code herepublic class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public int position;

    public MyOnItemSelectedListener(int p) {
        position = p;
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

        LSsearchCriteria.set(position,Herbalist.encodeoptions(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()));

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
```

`public int position;

    public MyOnItemSelectedListener(int p) {
        position = p;
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

        LSsearchCriteria.set(position,Herbalist.encodeoptions(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()));

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}`

Comment: Can you post your code, please? We don't know if you have extra listeners or something that is messing up your code.

Comment: I posted the source code. Note, that the spinner correctly initializes on selection 2. Once it scrolls off and on the screen again, it shows selection 0!

Comment: In your code above, what does your MyOnItemSelectedListener do when an item is selected? I ask because I think it gets fired when you call setSelection(2) immediately after setting the listener.

Comment: I think, it doesn't matter if it gets fired or not. All I do is save the selection into a List. I added MyOnItemSelectedListener above. If it fires when calling setSelection it sets something wrong into the list, but this does not explain why its displaying selection 0 once back on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to keep track of the state of the spinners in a separate data structure and when that row is bound again, initialize the spinner with your saved state.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But what method is called when the spinner is bound again? Where (and how) can I reinitialize the state of a spinner?

Comment: That depends on the type of adapter you are using for the list. If you are just implementing a ListAdapter, you would do the binding in `getView()`. If you are using a CursorAdapter, it also has a `bindView()` method that will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spinner.setSelection(i, true) instead.

Kudos go to Sagi at
http://sagistech.blogspot.com/2010/12/spinnersetselection-doesnt-work.html